# How to add custom column name in sqlalchemy update query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a following question:

I use sqlalchemy within my python method as follows:

```py
def update_icao_airport_id(self, airport_sys_id, project_sys_id, custom_column, value):
        """
        Updates Airport icao_airport_id value.
        :param airport_sys_id: airport_sys_id value you want to change
        :param project_sys_id: project_sys_id which is associated with Airport
        :param value: icao_airport_id new value
        :return: number of rows affected
        """
        query = AIRPORT.update(). \
            where(AIRPORT.c.airport_sys_id == airport_sys_id). \
            where(AIRPORT.c.project_sys_id == project_sys_id). \
            values(custom_column=value)
        result = self.execute_query(query)
        return result
```

I want to be able to replace 'custom_column' with parameter passed in the method. There is no way for me to work for column name, it works only for values after '=' or '==' fine for airport_sys_id, project_sys_id and value.

For example I want to pass in my method (1, 2, name_column, cat) and receive as follows:

```py
query = AIRPORT.update(). \
            where(AIRPORT.c.airport_sys_id == 1). \
            where(AIRPORT.c.project_sys_id == 2). \
            values(name_column=cat)
```

I searched all I could but with no success. I would be extremely thankful for your support. Regards.

Comment: You should have been able to do that: "The keys within values can be either Column objects or their string identifiers (specifically the “key” of the Column, normally but not necessarily equivalent to its “name”)." https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html

Comment: I cannot.. "Parameter custom_column value is not used". It doesn't recognize that I want to use parameter, but treats 'custom_column' in the query independently.

Comment: Pass strings to your function for column name and string values, like: `update_icao_airport_id(1, 2, "name_column", "cat")`.

Comment: It doesn't work, python doesn't match custom_column from method parameter with custom_name inside the query.

Comment: If your column name on database level is "column_name" and its type is string, then `.update("column_name"="domething") should work. If you check your database and actual column name is "name", then `.update("name"="something")` should work. I don't see any reason why it fails for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a working solution for my example:

We can use a dictionary:

```
.values({custom_column: value})
```

And then I can use it in my query like this:

```
update_values = {custom_column: value}

query = AIRPORT.update(). \
        where(AIRPORT.c.airport_sys_id == airport_sys_id). \
        where(AIRPORT.c.project_sys_id == project_sys_id). \
        values(update_values)
```